# Best practice : Hide unused parameter

Tags: c++

I'm adding a method in class which has some parameters but still needs to be implemented later.

I.e.

```
void AAA::doSmth(const int32_t status)
{
    // TODO : Add implementation
}
```

During compilation I get warning about unused parameter.
Basically what I want to do is to do some trick that makes compiler to not print warning about unused parameter, but still keep empty implementation.

So I would like to know what is the best practice to have some "dummy" usage of parameter in order to avoid the warning during compilation ? What is the best practice ???

**Please do not offer any IDE or compiler related option to hide the warning !!!**

Comment: You can just remove (or comment) the parameter name; it's optional.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually simply comment out the parameter like so:

```
void AAA::doSmth(const int32_t /*status*/)
{
    // TODO : Add implementation
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if you want to comment the function as well. In which case using ```(void) status;``` in the body is working as well.

Comment: Please note that if there were a default value for the parameter unused, you don't have to comment it, for example : void AAA::doSmth(const int32_t /*status*/ = 51). This will let you call the method without the parameter.